# MS Access: Generate report for each entry in table

Tags: vba, ms-access, report

I want to get a minimal example running in access where I basicly print a school report sheet for each student in a list. This is what I started working with:
[image: ERM-model]

Here "Schueler" is "student", "Note" is "school grade" and "Fach" is "school subject". Pretty straight forward I hope.

In the table "Note" is the information about which student gets which grade:

[image: data for the students]

So for the subject 1 (math) student 1 (peter) gets the grade 4.
he also gets the grade 2 in German.
Student 2 (Hans) gets a 6 in math and a 1 in German.

My question: I want to generate a series of reports which will basicly generate a grade sheet for every student. (So in this example Hans and Peter, if there are more students it should print more sheets)
The output should look something like this:

```
Grade sheet
Name: Peter
Math: 4
German: 2
```

//next page

```
Grade sheet
Name: Hans
Math: 6
German: 1
```

Thanks for looking into it :)

Comment: Which language? Raw sql? php? Java? You should also add a tag for the required language

Comment: What exacly have you tried?

Comment: I am doing this  with MS Access, so if possible with the GUI (whatever is underlying - probably SQL?). If it has to be, with VBA.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add a report and a page break on the IDSchuelerF field.  Please see this link for all details.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-a-page-break-control-in-an-Access-report-86d2ea7d-7aa6-44f2-8507-23134a9a2e15